# Out-of bag error in Random Forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, out-of-sample

I am trying to code my own, simple version of RandomForest function in R for learning purposes. However I have a hard time understanding the concept of the out-of-bag error.

Is it simply done by computing for each tree the error on sample not seen during training?  So for example if my tree was build of 60% of dataset, I compute the error on remaining 40% of dataset, I repeat that logic for each tree and average the results?

Or am I misunderstanding something?

[Edit] My confusion comes from this definition:

[image]

Because this definition seems different to what my intuition says.

Comment: Wouldn't the remaining sample be 40%?

Comment: But other than that your thinking is right

Comment: BTW, this question may have already been answered on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541923/what-is-out-of-bag-error-in-random-forests

Answer (score 1):

You train each tree, $T$, with a subset of the training set (a bootstrap sample), and some of the samples are left out. So, for each tree in the forest, there are *out of the bag samples*. If I didn't misunderstand you, you test these tree-specific OOB samples on the tree, $T$, and calculate the error, do this for every tree, and average the *errors*, which is not the way you do normally, and in the explanation in your image. Here, you test your samples on *trees*, not the *forest*.

Just like you have a subset of samples for each tree, conversely, for each sample, $x_i$, you have a set of trees that your sample is *out of bag*, e.g. $T_i=\{T_{i1},T_{i2},...,T_{im}\}$ set of trees that don't contain $x_i$ in their sample subset. You calculate predictions of $x_i$ on this smaller forest, average them, which creates $\hat{y}^{oob}$ and then calculate your error. You do this for each sample in your dataset, and obtain the *OOB* error.

Comment: thank you !

but I have one further question. Let's say that my explanatory variables are denoted Xi = [Xi1,Xi2..Xim]. In each tree I randomly sample 60% of m variables. If so, every tree will be 'out of sample' as I will never have a tree that used (xi,yi) -> all variables in row 'i' as a train sample.  I hope  that my question makes sense.

Comment: But, you're using that specific sample, i.e. $x_i,y_i$; it doesn't matter if you exploit all of its features or not. Testing philosophy is based on *unseen* samples.

Comment: Ok thank you ! and what if some xi,y weren't used in any tree? how to compute the  OOB classifier for them?

Comment: If the sample is not used in any trees, then every tree will include it in their test, (OOB) set for OOB error calculation, i.e. $T_i$ is the set of all trees.

Comment: oh sorry, the question was supposed to be the other way around, what if some xi,yi were used in EVERY tree, how to compute OOB fo them?

Comment: simply you won't. You'll obtain $\hat{y}_{oob}$ for the others and estimate the error by averaging just these. $x_i$ cannot be tested. And, I find this very unlikely in practice since there will be many trees