# OOB in Random Forests - Detailed Calculation

Tags: references, random-forest, error, bagging

In the book An introduction to statistical learning, it is mentioned that:

> One can show
> that on average, each bagged tree makes use of around two-thirds of the
> observations. The remaining one-third of the observations not used to fit a
> given bagged tree are referred to as the out-of-bag (OOB) observations. We
> can predict the response for the ith observation using each of the trees in
> which that observation was OOB. This will yield around B/3 predictions
> for the ith observation. In order to obtain a single prediction for the ith
> observation, we can average these predicted responses (if regression is the
> goal) or can take a majority vote (if classification is the goal). This leads
> to a single OOB prediction for the ith observation. An OOB prediction
> can be obtained in this way for each of the n observations, from which the overall OOB MSE (for a regression problem) or classification error (for a
> classification problem) can be computed. The resulting OOB error is a valid
> estimate of the test error for the bagged model, since the response for each
> observation is predicted using only the trees that were not fit using that
> observation.

I think I understand the overall intuition, however, to be sure, I would greatly appreciate if someone could refer me to a tutorial/paper/etc (available online) that illustrates this with a simple example and a small forest (perhaps 2-3 trees). I have gone over other posts such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388095/out-of-bag-error-in-random-forest) but these are mostly high-level. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your specific question wrt OOB is not clear enough, at least to me. What kind of illustration are you seeking? And why wouldn't OOB metrics wrt error or loss not suffice?

Comment: Hi @MikeHunter I am new at this and trying to gain a deeper understanding, and examples help with that.

Comment: Statistical tests of any model's forecast performance are commonly conducted by splitting a given data set into an in-sample (training) data, used for the initial parameter estimation and model selection, and an out-of-sample (o-o-s, test) data, used to evaluate forecasting performance. Empirical evidence based on o-o-s forecast performance is generally considered more trustworthy than evidence based on in-sample performance, which can be more sensitive to outliers and data mining. Out-of-sample forecasts also better reflect the information available to the forecaster in "real time".

Comment: In the case of RFs, each iteration creates a *mini-tree* based on random bootstrap resampling of **both** observations and features with, as above, each iteration's resample partitioned into training and test or o-o-s data.